# SQL - CASE and OR statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with using two SQL statements, namely `CASE WHEN` and `OR`. I'm trying to do the following:

```
@variable1 = CASE @variable2 WHEN 2 THEN @variable2 + 2 OR @variable2 - 2
```

I want to perform a query, that looks for specific values of `@variable2` and then gives a choice of choosing one of two options after `THEN` statement. It does not work. Could someone please help me?

Comment: how can u store two values in a variable..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your post and use the Code Sample button or Ctrl+K to format your code snippets.

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: I don't want to store two variables, I want to have one of them - that is why I wanted to use OR statement, but if fails

Comment: @Tanner: T-SQL is SQL-Server.

Comment: I know there is no END, but it is not the point

Comment: When one variable equals 2 I want to have the other one equal either 2+2 or 2-2

Comment: @user3800885 just randomly or based on some logic?

Comment: Reduce this to `@variable1 = CASE @variable2 WHEN 2 THEN \@variable2 + 2 END`. So when @variable2 is 2 then @variable1 *is* @variable2 + 2 or @variable2 - 2. It's @variable2 + 2 then to be precise.

Comment: What if I would like to have two options: +2 and +3 instead of +/- 2?

Comment: Based on some logic related to the query I am writing

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to achieve:

```
@variable1 = CASE @variable2 
                 WHEN 2 THEN @variable2 + 2 
                 ELSE @variable2 - 2
             END
```

So if `@variable2 = 2` then you add 2, otherwise you subtract 2.

Is sounds like you want to either add or subtract a specified number form another number so here's a look at what you could do:

```
declare @BaseNumber int
set @BaseNumber = 10 -- number we want to add to or subtract from

declare @MathNumber int 
set @MathNumber = 5 -- number we want to add on or subtract from @BaseNumber 

declare @IsAddition bit
set @IsAddition = 1 -- true means we're adding not subtracting
```

Using `CASE`:

```
SELECT @BaseNumber = CASE @IsAddition 
                      WHEN 1 THEN @BaseNumber + @MathNumber
                      ELSE @BaseNumber - @MathNumber
                 END
```

Using `IF` block:

```
IF (@IsAddition)
    BEGIN
        SET @BaseNumber = @BaseNumber + @MathNumber
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @BaseNumber = @BaseNumber - @MathNumber
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can nest case

```
case @variable2
    when 2 then
        case when someCond
            then 4 -- @variable2 + 2
            else 0 -- @variable2 - 2
        end
    when 3 then @variable2 * 2
    else @variable2
end
```